# copy multiple files and give prefix and keep originals

Tags: bash, shell

how do i copy files in unix. i want to keep the originals and add a prefix to the originals.

i have the following:

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
file4.csv
...
fileX.csv
```

what I will end up with after giving the command(with "H_" being the prefix in this example):

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
file4.csv
...
fileX.csv
H_file1.csv
H_file2.csv
H_file3.csv
H_file4.csv
...
H_fileX.csv
```

I was looking at the `cp` or `mv` command, but have no luck yet

Comment: `rename 's/^/H_/' *.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in *.csv; do
    cp "$file" "H_$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

for f in *.csv; do cp -v -- "$f" "H_$f"; done